# htaccess/rewriterule and virtual folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

in the past I've used this site a few times through Google and found useful help to problems. Now I want to ask my own question and therefor registered. So, "Hi everybody!"

My "problem" involves htaccess-rewriterule and PHP/HTML.
Let's say I have a URL "http://www.mydomain.com/showdata.php?ID=9" and I want to rewrite is as "http://www.mydomain.com/person/firstname-lastname-9.php". My plan was that "person" would just be a virtual directory.
The rewriterule part was no problem:

```
RewriteRule ^person/(.*)-(\d+)\.php$ /showdata.php?ID=$2
```

The new URL leads to the right entry in the MySQL-database. The problem is that the CSS files are not being loaded and all the links in the navigation point to the "person" folder.
I thought I could "link" to a virtual folder, because the htaccess would lead the browser to the real file on the server. I could actually create the folder "person" and copy include-files in it, but that would mean I have to change alot of paths in my source code. That's a alot of messy work and I would rather avoid that.
Is there a way to have a virtual folder (for keywords), but still have the php script include files from the main folder?

Comment: Why not just rewrite to showdata.php? So the user sees `http://www.mydomain.com/person/firstname-lastname-9` but the server sees `http://www.mydomain.com/showdata.php?ID=9`

Comment: You are looking for `<base href=..>`

Comment: I have pages with anchor-links and I read that <base> doesn't work well with anchors.

Comment: ok, I made a compromise: I used the <base> tag and removed the 3 anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Add more rules for css,js, and images ..

I'll assume your css/js/images are in folders with names "css" , "js" , "images"

e.g

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(images|css|js)/(.*) /$1/$2 [L]
# | means OR  , [L] means last rule i.e. do not continue to process other rules after this.
```

Comment: A `RewriteCond` might be easier in such cases.